# Reactjs: Show logged in or log in accordingly to session

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I am trying to get better in react and I would like to do it everything correctly which is why I am asking for your opinions and help.

I am building a project in NextJS and I have a layout component which contains components which are rendered multiple times such as header, footer etc.

I this header, I have a "Sign in" and "Sign out" button. I'd like it to only show one of them accordingly to your session status.

[image]

I use a sessionid which contains some more info in the database and this sessionid is stored in a httponly cookie.

[image]

It is stored in the database with data:

- id
- sessionid
- userid
- expires

Would you add or remove anything to this?

---

So my question is:

How would you check for a session and then render x accordingly? Would you just send an api call each request that checks the session or? Should I maybe use useContext and create a provider which can then send the session with the provider?

I'm quite lost on how to do it the best way so the flow is smooth as f*ck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how strict you want to be with it.

One option would be to simply check the existence of the cookie and adjust according to that. You can use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for that.

The better option, in my opinion, is to verify the cookie with your backend. You should set up an endpoint that simply verifies / parses the cookie and returns something like the user_id, or ismply a boolean indicating whether the user is logged in.

Given that you are using Next, you can add this call to your App's getInitialProps() like this:

```
  App.getInitialProps = async () => {

  let loggedIn;

  try {
    ({ data: {loggedIn} } = await axios.get('/api/v1/auth/checkCookie'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error checkingCookie', err.message );
  }

  return {
    loggedIn,
  }
}
```

Your loggedIn variable will then be available in the props of your App, like:

```
function App({currentUser}) {
if (currentUser) {
    return <div>Logged In</div>
} else {
    return <div>Logged Out</div>
}
}
```